# Search for text in a file, then rename the file with that text

Tags: command-line, scripts, batch-rename

We have a number of job reports from a system which save on our Linux server with the prefix `O*****.TXT`.  Within the file is the report's process ID.

What script can I run to search all `'O****.TXT` files in a directory, and rename each file with the process ID from each file?
eg:

Search `OAAJWNZN.TXT` for `ProcID:0000019324`, rename `OAAJWNZN.TXT` to `0000019324.TXT`.

Then once this file is renamed, the script moves onto the next file in the directory and does the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An awk command that reads the file and renames it:

```
awk -F '[:)]' '/ProcID/{printf "echo mv %s %s.txt\n", FILENAME, $2 | "/bin/sh"; nextfile}' O*.TXT
```

Since the `ProcID` line is actually:

```
JOB 04508907 (ProcID:0000019324) START AT 22.12.2016 / 09:10:45
```

To extract the I,P we need to split on both `:` and `)`, which will give us `0000019324` as the second field.

Remove `echo` to actually execute the move. Use this only if the filenames and `ProcID` don't contain spaces or special characters.

This command gets the `ProcID` by splitting on `:` to get the second field, then uses it and the special variable `FILENAME` to construct the command. [GNU awk's documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Functions.html#index-system_0028_0029-function) suggests the `printf ... | "/bin/sh"` method. Then we skip to the next file.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for the response.  The line in the file it is pulling the ProcID from is as follows:
 JOB 04508907 (ProcID:0000019324) START AT 22.12.2016 / 09:10:45

When running the suggested script, I get the following.
/bin/sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
/bin/sh: line 1: `mv OAAJWNZN.TXT 0000019324) START AT 22.12.2016 / 09.txt'

What do I need to change?

Comment: @IanG is the ProcID line always of the form `JOB X (ProcID:Y) ...`?

Comment: yes, the process ID is always on this line and in this format.

Comment: @IanG just change `-F:` to `-F '[:)]'`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Great, thanks.  that worked with only one file in a directory.  I have now added multiple files to the directory and ran the script, but had an error returned?
awk -F '[:)]' '/ProcID/{printf "mv %s %s.txt", FILENAME, $2 | "/bin/sh"; nextfile}' O*.TXT
mv: target `0000015947.txt' is not a directory

Comment: @IanG there's a `\n` after `%s.txt` there. You really should be running the command with `echo mv` first.

Comment: Hi Muru.  Can I change this so that it only renames files once it find 'ProdID' for a second time in the file. eg, once the report has finished writing out.  Or when it find ProcID 2 lines before the word Job Ended.

Comment: the line I would like it to read is similar to the example below.  Then once it reads the lines with ProcID and Ended on the same line, then it renames the file.     JOB 04475120 (ProcID:0000017814) ENDED AT 13.12.2016 / 10:27:17

Comment: @IanG just change `/ProcID/` to `/ProcID.*ENDED/`, I suppose. Please stop posting endless variations in comments.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `for`, `rename` and `sed` in the directory where the files are:

```
for i in O*.TXT; do rename -n "s/.*\.TXT/$(sed -nr 's/.*( |^)ProcID:([0-9]+)( |$).*/\2/p' "$i").TXT/" "$i"; done
```

Remove `-n` after `rename` after testing to actually rename the files

#### Explanation

- `for i in O*TXT; do` do something with all the matching files
- `rename -n` just report what the new names will be, don't actually rename them yet (remove `-n` after testing)
- `"s/old/new/"` replace `old` with `new` (use double instead of single quotes so we can pass variables with `$` expansion)
- `$(command)` command substitution - pass output of `command` to something else
- `.*\.TXT` match any characters followed by literal `.` and then `TXT`
- `sed` invoke our friend `sed` to read the file and extract things from it
- `-n` don't print anything until we ask for it
- `-r` use ERE so we don't have to escape `()` or `+`
- `( |^)` space or start of line
- `ProcID:([0-9]+)` at least one digit after ProcID... save the number for later
- `( |$)` space or end of line
- `\2` back reference to pattern saved earlier with `()`
- `p` print the result after editing

Answer (score 4):

1. Loop through the files.
2. You can use grep for finding the ProcID
3. Move the file to the new filename

Do a cp instead of mv if you want to keep the old files or you are not sure.

```
for file in 0*.TXT; do
  procid=$(grep -Po "(?<=ProcID:)[0-9]*" "$file");
  new_filename="/outputpath/${procid}.TXT";
  if [ ! -f "$newfilename" ]; then
    mv "$file" "$new_filename";
  fi;
done
```